# how to wrap two string with double quote that are separated by comma in JS

Tags: javascript, data-conversion

I am very new to coding. I am having issue solving this following:
taking a data block ex:

```
1963;john, doe;Williwanka,tp;jane;4200;1300;19.63;-42
```

and covert into something like

```
1963,"john, doe","Williwanka,tp",jane,4200,1300,19.63,-42
```

I know I can use `split()` and `join()` however having trouble sorting through the string separated by comma "," and add double quote.

```js
let text = "00077;Jessica;Williamsburg,ky;40769;42;42;42;42";
var myArray = text.split(";");
var newText = "";

for (var i = 0; i <= myArray.length; i++) {
  if (myArray.indexOf(i) == ",") {
    let newText = '"' + fruits.join('","') + '"';
  } else {
    newText += text.index(i);
  }
}
return newText
```

Answer (score 1):

Split by semicolons, then for each part, check if it includes a comma. If it does, wrap it in quotes, otherwise, don't change it. Then join the result into a string.

```js
const text = "1963;john, doe;Williwanka,tp;jane;4200;1300;19.63;-42";

const parts = text.split(";");

const result = parts.map((p) => p.includes(",") ? `"${p}"` : p).join(",");

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the regex `/([^;]+)(?:;|$)/` and replace the first capturing group with `"` if it cannot be parsed to a number.

```js
const input = "1963;john, doe;Williwanka,tp;jane;4200;1300;19.63;-42",
      replacer = (_, p1) => isNaN(p1) ? `"${p1}",` : `${p1},`,
      output = input.replace(/([^;]+)(?:;|$)/g, replacer).slice(0, -1);

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answers are correctly fine, it might be hard to understand how they work for a novice programmer.

Allow me to fix give you another answer below which is based on a simple loop like the OPs original code.

```js
let text = "00077;Jessica;Williamsburg,ky;40769;42;42;42;42";
var partsArray = text.split(";");
var newText = "";


for (var i = 0; i < partsArray.length; i++) {
  let onePart = partsArray[i];

  if (onePart.includes(",")) {
    newText += `"${onePart}"`;
  } else {
    newText += onePart;
  }
  newText += ",";
}

console.log(newText);
```